# Zooming an element and its contents-- an alternative to CSS3's zoom property?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

Is there a cross-browser method to emulate [CSS3's zoom property](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/)?  I know how to zoom images and text separately, but cannot seem to keep everything aligned.

One solution might be to read the computed styles of the element and its children, convert all measures to px, multiply them by some factor, and then generate HTML/CSS with these new styles.  Another solution might actually make sense. :)

Important: A correct solution assumes nothing about the page it acts on.  We don't know that every element is sized in px, styled by an external stylesheet, or anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is not a CSS3 property, it is an IE-only property (and deprecated in IE9).

Comment: You can use CSS3 `transform`. E.g. `transform: scale(1.5);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) library that provides [Effect.Scale](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/effect-scale) functionality.