# How to zoom in gradually in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

Let's say I have a webpage, of a cat staring on me. The image will then start zooming in on the cats eyes. Deeper, and deeper....How can I make this in HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Comment: I think it is an interesting question, especially the "on the cats eyes" part. Why closing?

Comment: Looking at these other questions could help you: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135894/zooming-an-element-and-its-contents-an-alternative-to-css3s-zoom-property) - [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028557/how-to-zoom-in-an-image-and-center-it) - [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130186/javascript-html-css-zooming)

Comment: @Sebas - The question is overly broad and covers too many topics and I'm assuming the OP needs a lot of cross tech education.

Comment: @Rob Seems pretty simple to me, if you ignore the silliness of the question's phrasing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply a CSS3 scale transform:

```
$("#cat").attr('style', "transform: scale(4,4);-ms-transform: scale(4,4);-webkit-transform: scale(4,4);-o-transform: scale(4,4);-moz-transform: scale(4,4);");
```

...with a slow CSS3 transition:

```
#cat {
    transition: transform 120s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 120s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 120s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 120s;
}
```

...and here's your cat! http://jsfiddle.net/x5uYp/

Comment: That looks cool. Props to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ths isn't zooming, just scaling.

Have an `<img />` with your cat, then use JavaScript, with `setTimeout` every 100ms or so, to increase the `width` and `height` attributes.

Comment: you may as well zoom...

Comment: How do I make it so that the height and width changes? Can you use variables in HTML? I'm confused.